# Changing the Mod key in Awesome WM

Tags: linux, hotkeys, xmodmap, awesome-wm

I tried to change the mod key in awesome from the windows key to either Pause, Scroll Lock, and Escape.

For all keys I tried to change the entry in the `rc.lua` configuration file; I tried to use xmodmap to clear locks and `add mod4 = ...`

However it seems that no matter what I do the keys get "sticky" (sometimes in a weird inconsistent way), namely if I hit them once the computer acts as though they are constantly pressed.

Is there a reasonable way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I have a file with these two lines in my home:

```
clear lock 
keysym Caps_Lock = Super_L
```

It gets called from my *rc.lua* like this:

```
awful.util.spawn("xmodmap /home/username/your_xmodmap.file")
```

Comment: I don't want to use capslock as the modkey. the `clear lock` command clears shift lock, and there shouldn't be any shift lock for either keys mentioned in the first line of my question.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am 3 years late, but if this helps anyone, switch

```
modkey = "Mod4"
```

with

```
modkey = "Mod1"
```

Comment: That's the basic concept, but the specific keys he listed can't be used with a simple modification like that to the rc.lua.  The modkey setting in the rc.lua can apparently only be set to keys that xmodmap treats as modifier keys (like shift or ctrl), and can't be set to something like 'x'.

Comment: this helped me!

Answer (score 2):

Way late, but for others' reference:

The problem seems to be that xmodmap isn't identifying any of the keys you listed as modifier keys.  AwesomeWM therefore doesn't allow them to be used as modifier keys.

You can try adding the key you want to use as Mod3 (which doesn't seem to be used for anything on most systems I've seen), then your rc.lua can list the modkey as "Mod3".

### Add as a modifier key

You can see your modifier keys with `xmodmap`.  By default you'll probably get something like this:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

With `xev` you can see the name of any key you press while it's running, and for Scroll Lock mine shows up as:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x225, subw 0x0, time 23086947, (433,729), root:(470,783),
    state 0x0, keycode 78 (keysym 0xff14, Scroll_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x225, subw 0x0, time 23087091, (433,729), root:(470,783),
    state 0x0, keycode 78 (keysym 0xff14, Scroll_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

You'll notice the name of the keysym is `Scroll_Lock`.  

To add to Mod3, you need to create or add to `~/.Xmodmap`.  Adding this line sets Mod3 to be only the Scroll_Lock key:

```
add Mod3 = Scroll_Lock
```

To test your changes and see any errors in your .Xmodmap file, run

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

### Updating rc.lua

As you've clearly already figured out, toward the top of your rc.lua file (which is usually in `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua`), there's a `modkey = "Mod4"` line.  Change this to `modkey = "Mod3"`.

### Warnings

The Esc key is used for a number of key mappings by AwesomeWM.  I'd suggest trying Scroll Lock or Pause instead since it's less likely to have extensive conflicts.  In fact AwesomeWM seems to assume Esc is reserved for canceling the current operation.

Scroll Lock seems to be magically treated as a locking key, much like Caps Lock.  The difference is that the locking behavior of Caps Lock is relatively trivial to disable, while Scroll Lock can't have this behavior disabled as far as I can tell. 

I'd suggest trying this with a key like the Numpad 0 key, or something that's not normally designed to be a state locking key, confirm it works, then try switching to the key you want.